# onclick function to add 5 to variable

Tags: javascript, html, xml, onclick

I have two variables:
**strt** and **num**. 
**strt** = 0; 
**num** = 5;

I want to write an onclick function that adds 5 each time a link is clicked, so the variables keep going up by 5. 
I've tried many different functions but nothing works for this. 
Please help!

I'll go into a little more detail : 
I am displaying articles from a newspaper XML feed here. 
On clicking a link, I want to display 5 more. 
I am already displaying 5. 
The variables I am changing belong inside a for loop: 
Here is part of my code:

```
var strt = 0;
var num = 5;

increment = function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //maybe needed? Prevent Default a link behavior.
strt = strt + 5;
num = num + 5;
}

for (i = strt; i < num; i++)
{       
document.write("<div class='article'><span class='title'><a target='_blank' href='"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"'>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</a></span><h2>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</h2></div>");
}

// Onclick add 5 more articles
document.write("<div id='more'><a href='#' onclick='increment(event)'>Some Link</a></div></div>");
```

The code seems to work when I am adding 5 to each variable but they are not changing inside the for loop. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the code of your best try, at it would make your question much more likely to get answered.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

**HTML**

```
<a href="somelink" onclick="increment(event)">Some Link</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
var strt = 0;
var num = 0;

increment = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //maybe needed? Prevent Default a link behavior.
    strt = strt + 5;
    num = num + 5;
}
```

[Fiddle of the above.](http://jsfiddle.net/yabf1gsc/)

Comment: @CharlotteOswald This code will work. Did you include your Javascript files in your page?

Comment: @CharlotteOswald Please see the included fiddle

Comment: I've added more detail to my question.. perhaps you will be able to see why it isn't working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this complete code:

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
var strt = 0;
var num = 0;

function increment(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //maybe needed? Prevent Default a link behavior.
    strt = strt + 5;
    num = num + 5;   
      alert(num);

}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <a href="somelink" onclick="increment(event)">Some Link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```